# Turing Equivalence counterexample

Tags: computability, turing-machines

Given that A is Turing reducible to B, what would the set B need to look like such that B is *not* Turing reducible to A? I've been having a hard time with this idea and I would appreciate some examples where this is the case.

Comment: What if $A$ is computable and $B$ is not computable?

Comment: Finding an example where $A$ is reducible to $B$ but $B$ is not reducible to $A$ isn't going to be much harder than just finding an example where $B$ is not reducible to $A$. Because, if $A,B\subseteq\mathbb N$ are such that $B$ is not reducible to $A$, then $A$ and $B$ are both reducible to $C=\{2n:n\in A\}\cup\{2n+1:n\in B\}$, so $A$ is reducible to $C$ but $C$ is not reducible to $A$. So you might as well simplify your question by just asking for an example of $A$ and $B$ such that $B$ is not Turing reducible to $A$. (Do they have to be recursively enumerable sets, or will any old sets do?)